# Why splice works on object's array type attribut when vuex's doc says it shouldn't?

Tags: vue.js, components, state, vuex

I have a vuex state state that looks like this :

```
state: {
  myObj: {someArrayAttribut: [...], ...}
}
```

In my component :

```
computed: {
  ...mapState("module", [myObj])
},
methods: {
  remove(i) {
    this.myObj.someArrayAttribut.splice(i, 1)
  }
}
```

The method remove works and its great, but the vuex doc clearly says that
`The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation.`

I feel like I can wasted a lot of time declaring mutations when I can update states directly in the component.

So what is wrong with what I have done ?

Comment: The introduction to Vuex at [What is Vuex?](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) is basically the answer to your question.

Comment: My bad, I didn't express my problem right. It's more "Why does it work ?" rather than "Why is it wrong ?"

I think I understand the best practice, but it states again `with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion`.

Is it that the rules is theorical and not enforced ?

It seems trivial, but I think it changes the mindset when troubleshotting to know how high is the safety net.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood `Vuex` uses the same reactivity system as `Vue`. So anything that will trigger an update in Vue will trigger an update in Vuex.

This is the case for `Array.splice` and others.

The main reason why you shouldn't update the state from outside mutations is that mutations also ensure data integrity.

By updating the state directly you lose this and trying to debug problems like this is a big pain.